# Regex: how do I capture the file extension?

Tags: regex

How do I determine the file extension of a file name string?

lets say I have

I'm.a.file.name.tXt

the regex should return tXt

Comment: Many languages have built-in ways of handling filenames and extensions. What are you using?

Comment: Doesn't the language/platform you are using to run regexes have file handling routines?

Comment: I'm curious: why are you writing `tXt` every time, rather than `txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like `\.[^.]*$` should do it

Comment: As an extension, you possibly want make to the `\.` a lookbehind - so `(?<=\.)[^.]*$` - to avoid potentially having to remove the `.` later. Though not all regex implementations support lookbehinds, and we don't know what one this is for.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need regex - most languages will have the equivalent to this:

```
ListLast(Filename,'.')
```

(If you do need regex for some reason, [Scharron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292547/regex-how-do-i-capture-the-file-extension/3292560#3292560) is correct.)

Answer (score 0):

What language is this in? It's quite possible you don't want to actually use a regex - assuming the name is a String you'll probably just want to do something like split it over periods and then choose the last segment. Okay, that's sort of a regex answer, but not a proper one.

Answer (score -2):

```
/^(.*?)\.(.*)$/
```

The '?' makes it greedy. Your result will be in the second group.

Comment: I'm, and 
a.file.name.tXt not just tXt

Comment: In which case remove the greedy match at put it on the second group.

You said you only wanted 'tXt'.

Comment: The `?` makes a quantifier **lazy**, *not* greedy!

Comment: Based on your comment, you possibly misunderstand greedy vs lazy matching. Read more at http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html but basically, if taking this approach, you want `(greedy).(lazy)` in order to consume as much as possible for the first group and as little as required for the second.